# knockout template binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-templating

I have an ul element which is filled through template binding.

```
<script type="text/html" id="someTemplate">
<li>
   <span data-bind="text: someText">
</li>
</script>

<ul data-bind="template: {foreach: someElemets, name: 'someTemplate'}">
</ul>
```

But I want **the first** li-tag would not be li-tag from template but another one with button in it and it will not be connected to someElemets array. If I do in that way

```
<ul data-bind="template: {foreach: someElemets, name: 'someTemplate'}">
    <li><button data-bind=click: doSomething">Click me</button></li>
</ul>
```

then li-tag with button will be the last one after rendering. What is the best way to solve that problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use containerless control flow syntax, databinding using comment tags. No need for a template. [more info](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

```
<ul>     
    <li><button data-bind=click: doSomething">Click me</button></li>
    <!-- ko foreach: someElemets-->         
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: someText"></span>
    </li>    
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Exactly. Containerless (html/ko comment) control of flow bindings are ideal for this situation. You can do foreach, if, ifnot, with, and template in them without having to create a DOM element just for KO.

Answer (score 7):

The following will do it:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'template-name', data: vm } --> <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an easy way to access the index when inside a template. You could use template options as described at [How to use foreach with a special first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371772/knockout-js-foreach-but-with-a-special-element-first)

Your code would be something like:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'someTemplate', foreach: someElemets, templateOptions: { first: someElemets()[0]} }">
</ul>

<script id="someTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li>
    {{if $item.first === $data}}
      <button data-bind="click: doSomething">Click me</button>
    {{/if}}
    <span data-bind="text: someText">
    </li>
</script>
```

Comment: and if I want to use that variant I should add empty first element to the someElemets array? looks like a cheat :)

Comment: You could just replace the {{else}} with {{/if}} so that the <span> is always rendered. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: One question, perhaps anyone know why when I am using `$data` and `$item` keywords - template is not rendered, but when accessing elements passed in `foreach` by ViewModel field names - all works fine, for instance I bound viewModel with array of users (with single `name` field), then binding to `name` work in template, but when using `$data` or `$item` - can't get it working

Comment: @sll - you should be able to use $data, although I believe $item belongs to tmpl so if you are using the KO native templates then you will not be able to use $item. Maybe post a new question if you still have problems.