# How to run functions in afterRender in knockout binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to add a datepicker to a textbox input, whose visibility is controlled by a knockoutjs binding.

```
<!-- ko if: hasWorked -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="text" />
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

My guess is:

```
<!-- ko if: hasWorked, afterRender:initDatepicker -->
```

But it never worked.

What is the correct way to show a textbox and then run a function to process it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`afterRender` is only available to `foreach` and `template`.

Luckily, we can do containerless template.

So the solution:

```
<!-- ko template: {if: hasWorked,afterRender:initDatepicker} -->
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

---

### References:

- [Containerless template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276719/knockout-template-binding) The solution provided by **Maksym
  Kozlenko**. Not the selected answer.
- The use of `afterRender` in `template`, see the [knockout official documentation on template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), (scroll down to Note 4).