# knockout.js: using a containerless foreach on a <select> fails in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, knockout.js

In [RP Niemeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594420/rp-niemeyer)'s article [Knockout.js Performance Gotcha #3 - All Bindings Fire Together](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html), 
an approach to building a dropdown list is provided:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedOption">
    <!-- ko foreach: options -->
    <option data-bind="attr: { value: id }, text: name"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

This code is also in a jsfiddle from the article.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QjVNX/

However, when I employed this method of building a **select** in a project, 
it was working just fine, until I tested in Internet Explorer 8. IE8 failed and 
was "unable to parse bindings".

Indeed, running the fiddle from the article in IE8 also results in an error. 
Is there a way to build the **select** in IE8 (I assume IE8 or less)
using knockout's foreach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is definitely an issue.  I will have to update the post.  IE will strip comments from inside the select.

Here is an issue that we saw on github that is similar: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/578

One solution is to use Michael Best's `repeat` binding: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat.

One of the things that it allows you to do is repeat a single element multiple times with a different context.  So, in that case it would act similar to the containerless syntax, just without the comments.

Sample with repeat: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QjVNX/

You can also choose to use the other technique from the article (`isolatedOptions`), unless you need more control over your option elements.

Comment: Thanks for all the insight. While the repeat plugin looks nice, I'd rather avoid another javascript file dependency, so I'm going with the template binding. It's too bad the containerless control flow syntax does not work here.

Comment: Hey Ryan, I updated the JSFiddle as it's knockout-2.1.0.js reference was broken.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an issue, there is really no need to use a 'foreach' here. Knockout includes the 'options' binding for a select that quite happily works in IE8.

Please see the documentation here:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedOption">
    <!-- ko foreach: options -->
    <option data-bind="attr: { value: id }, text: name"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

Can be changed to:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedOption, options: options, optionsText: function(item) {return item.name}, optionsValue: function(item) {return item.id}></select>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had this weird Problem, that the binding was done, and dev tools showed the options in the DOM, but some of the options where not shown.. they where selectable, but just blank. changing to the options binding as suggested here solved the problem. Thanks!