# Moving the (knockout) foreach outside of the input SELECT tag gives me breeze problems

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm using knockout and breeze and working right now on a SELECT html tag.

Here is the actual implementation:

```
<select data-bind="value: vehicleId, foreach: $root.vehicles()">
    <option data-bind="text: registration(), value: id()"></option>
</select>
```

At runtime, it looks like this:

[image]

For testing purpose, I refactor this code. So I move the `foreach` away of the SELECT.

Here is the new implementation:

```
<select data-bind="value: vehicleId">
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.vehicles() -->
        <option data-bind="text: registration(), value: id()"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

[image]

When I test my page, I noticed that breeze did not work as expected with the second implementation. When I update data (in any input) breeze did not detect my update anymore. Usually, when I update something on my page, I have `datacontext.hasChanges()` which is true. Then I display buttons like `Save`, `Cancel`. Now this is not the case. If I go back to the original implementation, it works again. Very strange to me.

Any idea?

Thanks.

---

EDIT

I also take a look at this: [knockout.js: using a containerless foreach on a <select> fails in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723451/knockout-js-using-a-containerless-foreach-on-a-select-fails-in-internet-explo)

but it does not seems to work either.

Comment: Curious. If the first implementation works, why the need to change?  I would assume the change event is raised by select tag. Technically your option values are never changing, only in the context of the select tag.  Also, your "registration" and "Id" do not need to be KO observables, do they? KO can do a one-way bind, not everything has to be an observable.

Comment: Need to change for testing purpose and understand 'why' and 'how'. All my elements are observable because behind this is a query from breeze which do it...

Comment: What are you changing that is not updated? The `vehicleId` of some outer databound object? Hard to tell without a little more info

Comment: Any updated data on my page even what does no relation with this select (like input boxes, ...). In this case (with the second implementation of my code) breeze did not refresh the status of `manager.hasChangesChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted at the bottom is absolutely correct - the comments are being stripped out of the select box.

The problem is not that Breeze isn't working - it's that your Knockout bindings in the view are breaking, specifically the value binding in the select box.  There are two approaches that work flawlessly here, the first is the one that you posted first, and that works.  The second is using a computed for the options binding, which is a method that I prefer.

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedVehicle, options: vehicleOptions, optionsText: 'registration'"></select>
```

and in your view model having a computed observable array

```
var selectedVehicle = ko.observable();
var vehicleOptions = ko.computed(function () {
    var myArr = [];
    if (!selectedVehicle) { return myArr; }
    return myArr = (refreshVehicles());
});
function refreshVehicles() {
    // Go get vehicles or w/e based on selectedVehicle
    var locVehicles = getVehicles(selectedVehicle());
    return locVehicles;
}
```

This does a few things -

1. It sounds like you are using cascading dropdowns of some sort, and the computed will be refactored whenever selectedVehicle changes.  If it is not cascading, then you can probably skip this and directly set the value of vehicleId or w/e.
2. It removes the need for the additional containerless binding, and it also cleans up the view by moving logic into the view model.