# knockout - Using containerless control flow syntax on select option

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js

I want to show/hide an option element inside a select element.

I tried using the *containerless control flow syntax*:

```
<select>        
    <!-- ko if: 'a'=='b'-->
        <option>option1</option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

The option element still renders on the DOM with an empty value (Causing the combo box to have blank line).

I've also tried using the regular *"if" binding* :

```
<select>               
        <option data-bind:"if('a'=='b')">option1</option>       
</select>
```

But it dose not have any effect.

Can I use *containerless control flow syntax* or *"if" binding* ?
Is there another way to achieve that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [knockout.js: using a containerless foreach on a <select> fails in Internet Explorer 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723451/knockout-js-using-a-containerless-foreach-on-a-select-fails-in-internet-explo)

Comment: Your example works for me in Chrome. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zdK6E/

Comment: The fiddle @Charlie linked worked for me in the latest versions of Chrome, IE, and Firefox

Comment: I need it to work in IE9 also